# How to "undraw" an image

Tags: java, image, drawing

I'm making a game in Java and I have it so that when the player presses the left arrow button, three images are drawn one after the other.  But when the third image is drawn, you can still see the image drawn before it (I rotated the images to make it look more realistic). Is there anyway to "undraw" the images?  I've done some research and haven't found anything specific.

Comment: Draw a square with the background color?

Comment: Instead a reverting a drawing on a canvas (which would need you to cache the canvas as it was before), why don't you just add the three images as a child of a container? That way you can just remove them from the container when you don't need them anymore. Maybe you should make a sketch of how it looks now, and how it should look.

Comment: Hmm, sorry but I'm not familiar with that?  Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Keppil  +1 but for speed, we should set a `Clip` that covers the area occupied by the element (image of bullet, missile, enemy..) that needs erasing (or replacing with the original BG).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't undraw an image.  It sounds like the images aren't fully opaque.

Comment: Ok, then could somebody please explain how to do what maenu suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Not to be an over-complication junkie, but how about using OpenGL to draw them on quads. That way you can hide, show, rotate, animate, accelerate etc so much easier. And it will all be tons faster than with Swing/AWT. [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) library + [NeHe Tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) will quickly show you how to achieve this (really, you only need [this](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_01__05/22004/) and [this](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_06__10/17010/)). Or use [Unity](http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/) if you wanna do it even simpler and more portable.

Comment: I'll look into that for later, but at the moment I think I'm just going to stick with Swing and AWT.  Do you think that you could explain what Maenu said please?

Comment: Well, no, because I don't really understand what he means. At any rate, I'm guessing you use the Graphics object and call "draw" method on it to draw each of your 3 images. If you want to make one of them "go away" just clear your graphics with the background colour and just redraw only the images you want visible after the event.

Comment: The only problem with that is that there's more than one color in the background. =\

Comment: No, but, ok, draw background with multiple colors, draw images 1,2 and 3. User hits arrow key, image 2 needs to go away. Clear background with white, redraw the multiple colors on the background, redraw images 1 and 3 just like before and leave image 2 undrawn.